# Extract detached PKCS7 signature from PKCS7 (signature&data)

Tags: python, openssl, m2crypto

I want to break a PKCS7 signature that contains data + signature into separate: raw data & detached PKCS7 signature in python.

I can get the data fro the signature because the verification routine returns it, but how can I get the detached signature ?

```
def verify_pkcs7(data_bio, signature_bio, cacert_bio, format=X509.FORMAT_PEM):
    sm_obj = SMIME.SMIME()
    st = X509.X509_Store()

    st.add_cert(X509.load_cert_string(cacert_bio))
    sm_obj.set_x509_store(st)


    if format == X509.FORMAT_PEM:
        p7 = SMIME.load_pkcs7_bio(signature_bio)
    else:
        p7 = SMIME.PKCS7(m2.pkcs7_read_bio_der(signature_bio._ptr()), 1)


    sk = p7.get0_signers(X509.X509_Stack())
    sm_obj.set_x509_stack(sk)

    try:
        v = sm_obj.verify(p7, data_bio)
        if v:
            print "Client signature verified."
            with open('file.rar', 'wb') as ff:
                ff.write(v)
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
        print "*** INVALID CLIENT MESSAGE SIGNATURE ***"
```

My wild guess is that it one of [these](http://doc.astro-wise.org/M2Crypto.m2.html) functions.. I base my assumption on the fact that M2Crypto is a wrapper over OpenSSL.

Comment: I have a data.txt, which is the data that I want to sign, I am creating a PKCS7 signature that is composed of : data.txt + signature( of data.txt) = pkcs7 signature.
Now I received that pkcs7 signature and I want to extract the original data.txt and the signature into 2 different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `M2Crypto.SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7_bio` function will take a `BIO` buffer containing an `SMIME` message (consisting of the message data and the PKCS7 signature) and return a tuple of two values: a `PKCS7` object, and a `BIO` containing the message data. You can get the PKCS7 signature as text by using its `.write(buf)` with yet another `BIO`.

However, note that M2Crypto (still) doesn't have Python 3 support, so you will be limited to 2.7.

The M2Crypto "documentation" on this is not worth linking to, but this appears to be the underlying OpenSSL function used: http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SMIME_read_PKCS7(3)